# What, if any, is the precise definition of "substantively large"?

Tags: definition

I am told that while my estimates are not statistically significant, they are "substantively large". Is there a precise definition for the phrase "substantively large"?

If I say that my estimates (which are not statistically significant) are not "substantively large" while someone else insists that they are, how do we decide who is correct?

Comment: I would be wary of those who told you that. When the issue goes the other way--e.g., "a statistically significant difference too small to be of practical significance"--there is room for knowledge about the subject matter to inform the statistical finding. But if your results are not statistically significant to start with, it doesn't matter how "large" the values are; you have no statistical basis to state that the values differ from 0, if that was your null hypothesis.

Comment: I do not think there is such a thing as a formal rule to decide, like for example in the case of statistical significance ("test statistic bigger than critical value"). It will depend on the subject matter.

Comment: Whoever told you had better be the one to tell you what they meant by it.